# Como definir variável dentro do Método match (String)

Tags: javascript, variáveis, match

O que desejo é incluir a variável dentro do `(/.../)` e não o seu valor.

## Código:

```
var str = 'Seu texto aqui!';

if (str.match(/texto/)) {
        alert('Palavra encontrada.');
}
```

Ao invés de definir manualmente, pretendo algo dinâmico vindo de uma variável.

## Exemplo:

```
var res = document.getElementById('txt').value = 'texto';

var str = 'Seu texto aqui!';

if (str.match(/res/)) {
        alert('Palavra encontrada.');
}
```

Mas não funciona `(/res/)`, pois não estou conseguindo descobrir como jogar uma atribuição da variável dentro do método `match (String)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar o construtor [`new RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) assim:

```js
var res = 'texto';
var regex = new RegExp(res);

var str = 'Seu texto aqui!';
if (str.match(regex)) {
  alert('Palavra encontrada.');
}
```

Em casos de texto simples também podes usar o *String.indexOf*, nesse caso assim:

```js
var res = 'texto';

var str = 'Seu texto aqui!';
if (str.indexOf(res) > -1) {
  alert('Palavra encontrada.');
}
```